# generate ssh connections by using paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am using paramiko to generate ssh connections, but I could not generate ssh connections for all the machines. and I get an error for several machines:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
```

and my code is very simple:

```
try:
     tmp_ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
     tmp_ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
     tmp_ssh.connect(tmp_ip, 22, tmp_user, tmp_pswd, timeout = 5)

     tmp_res = ""
     if type(tmp_cmd) == type([]):
         for tmp_str in tmp_cmd:
             tmp_str = tmp_str.strip()
             if len(tmp_str) > 0:
                 tmp_in, tmp_out, tmp_err = tmp_ssh.exec_command(tmp_str)
                 tmp_ret = tmp_out.readlines()
                 tmp_res += "".join(tmp_ret)
     else:
         tmp_cmd = str(tmp_cmd)
         tmp_str = tmp_cmd.strip()
         if len(tmp_str) > 0:
             tmp_in, tmp_out, tmp_err = tmp_ssh.exec_command(tmp_str)
             tmp_ret = tmp_out.readlines()
             tmp_res += "".join(tmp_ret)
     tmp_ssh.close()

     print tmp_res
 except:
    print "ERROR"
```

I google several suggestions to solve this problem (for example, https://github.com/newsapps/beeswithmachineguns/issues/17) and I try as they suggest, but I still could not fix it.

have you met this problem before? how do you fix it?

ps. I also try ssh(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssh), it has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could fix this problem, that is, change the ssh protocal of these machines from ssh1 to ssh2, and paramiko would be OK.